# Clarification on AHA's definition of a "serious" condition

Tags: physical-health, hospital, guidelines, stable-condition

The AHA has [posted standard guidelines](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/news/media/patient_condition_updates.html) for hospitals to follow regarding patient conditions.

They define a **Serious** condition/status as:

> "*Vital signs may be unstable and not within normal limits. Patient is acutely ill*"

What is meant by "*acutely ill*"? Conscious, but in extreme pain? Bleeding profusely? What types of presentations would a patient need to be in, in order to be considered "acutely ill"?

Answer (score 2):

The [guidelines for these terms](https://web.archive.org/web/20081122053845/http://www.aha.org/aha/advisory/2003/030201-media-adv.html) seem purposefully vague; they are meant to maintain patient privacy while releasing a minimum of information for newsworthy cases. **The American Hospital Association does not provide further definitions for these terms**.

"Acute" in a medical context roughly means "immediate" or "in the short term"; it isn't ordinarily an indicator of *intensity* in a medical context. Someone who is "acutely ill" must be ill *now*: it's not that they're at risk of being ill in the future, there is *something* about their vital signs that is off *now*. Compared to "critical", someone in "serious" condition is seen to have a better likelihood of good outcomes; compared to "fair" they are seen to have a worse likelihood of good outcomes. Besides that, there is no quantitative definition for any of these terms, they're based on physicians' opinions about a given case. You can expect the labels to vary from person to person, hospital to hospital.

Comment: I find the usage of "acute" in medical sources often denotes severity in addition to immediateness. An example would be AMI. I think the [wikipedia page for the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_(medicine)) actually gives it good treatment.

Comment: @CareyGregory Agreed that maybe it's a bit more complex than I suggested, and also agreed that page gives a good treatment. I can't really think of a case where "acute" is used as a modifier to mean more serious, though; that is, people don't say "MI" when it's just a little bit of an MI, and "acute MI" when it's a particularly big one, at least not that I've noted.